# How to stop rendering a list of elements if they start to create a second line

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of tags in my react app

```js
<div>
  {tags.map((tag, index) => (
    <Tag>{tag/name}</Tag>
  ))}
</div>
```

This get rendered in a div that takes the full width of the container. If the width of all the tags goes beyond the width of the div, it falls to the next line. However I want to not render the additional tags if a new line is required, I want to limit it to one line max. Is this possible?

Comment: Limiting the rendering would require working out the width of the container and the items, if you are just doing this for appearance reasons (rather than performance), I would do it with CSS. Hiding the overflow and limiting the containers height to 1 row should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for purely appearance reasons, a quick CSS solution would be to limit the height of the container and hide its overflow.

Non-React example (so it runs easily in a snippet):

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 20px;
  
  /* This is just for the example */
  border: 1px solid #000;
  resize: horizontal;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span>  <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span>  <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span> <span>Example Tag</span>
</div>
```